# Why does PowerShell ISE hang on this C# program?

Tags: c#, powershell, freeze, powershell-ise

If I compile this c# code to an EXE file and run in a Windows command shell it runs fine: outputting the prompt, waiting on the same line for some user input followed by enter,  echoing that input. Running in a PowerShell v3 shell it also runs fine. If, however, I run this same EXE file in PowerShell ISE V3, it never emits output from `Write` and it hangs on the `ReadLine`. (As an aside, it will emit output from `Write` if it is later followed by a `WriteLine`.)

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.Write("invisible prompt: ");
            var s = System.Console.ReadLine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("echo " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this an ISE bug or is there some property to adjust to make it work...?

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant but in Powershell it sometimes called *Keyboard Polling* which can implement certain issues. So maybe when `Console.ReadLine()` is called due to Powershell using that polling it maybe causing a conflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISE has no support for the `console` class.

> - No support for the [Console] class, try [console]::BackgroundColor  =
>     'white'.
>
>   - In general, scripts should use the host API's (write-host,
>       instead of the [Console] class, so that they work in both the console,
>       ISE, Remoting and other shells.

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/04/17/differences-between-the-ise-and-powershell-console.aspx

Comment: Andy: You have made me realize that the question I should have asked depends on the answer: if there was a workaround/setting/etc. then this question would be good as is, but since you point out there is _not_ then the better question should have been something like: _is there some way to read inputs in C# from ISE without using the console?_ But I did not know that a priori. Anyway, you answered it as asked so you get the checkmark--thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, in powershell ise, instead of calling `.\ConsoleApplication1.exe` call `start .\ConsoleApplication1.exe`
This will start the application in a new command prompt, that will accept input from stdin.

Comment: +1 That is a handy workaround--thanks for suggesting it!

Answer (score 0):

Powershell read-host will read from the console. You could execute the read-host from within C#. Executing PS commands from C# is documented on MSDN in the sections about Powershell hosting. The following demonstrates the methods calls with a Powershell script - should be easy to convert to C#. Note that $host must be passed into the C# program. Therefore you'd have to load the C# program as an assembly within ISE and invoke Main() like: [myclass]::Main($host) (versus invoking the EXE as a standalone program)

```
[powershell]::create().AddScript('param($ho) $ho.ui.readline()').AddArgument($host).Invoke()
```